# Javascript returns "Undefined"

Tags: javascript, undefined

I am trying to upload a file using `input[type=file]` and at form submit (which contains other elements like "first name", "last name" etc), I am converting the file to string and pass it as JSON to a server.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="resume" accept=".doc, .docx, .pdf" />
```

**Script:**

```
var resume = document.getElementById('resume').files[0];
var result = getbase64(resume);
console.log(result);
```

This returns `undefined` but the `console.log` inside the actual method logs the correct content when the above line calls the method.

```
function getBase64(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function () {
        var result = reader.result;
        console.log('here---->   '+result);
        return result;
    };
    reader.onerror = function (error) {
        console.log('Error: ', error);
    };
}
```

My question is how to correctly assign this return type to a variable so I can send it as String to the server.

Comment: `getBase64` doesn’t return anything. A `return` inside an event listener like `onload` is meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return statement `return result` does not return what you expect since it is in an event listener. That is, the output of function `getBase64` will be `Undefined`.  You can simply pass a callback function to transfer the file when the load event happens.

```
function getBase64(file, transferMyFile) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function () {
        var result = reader.result;
        console.log('here---->   '+result);
        transferMyFile(result)
        /* Or just transfer it here */
    };
    reader.onerror = function (error) {
        console.log('Error: ', error);
    };
}
```